# Issues Loading Multiple GLB models in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

So the scope of the project I'm working on is to have a simple character customizer. The gui will generate the different parts such as head, face, hands etc.

I've used the following as a backbone for the project as I'm still fairly new to ThreeJS and a different stackoverflow topic pointed the person to this example for swapping out models.
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=ld#webgl_loader_ldraw

I've been able to get most everything working and stable but the issue I'm running into is that when I try to Load the .glb model the console states that there was an error loading.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the Code:

```
        import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import { GLTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
        import { GUI } from './jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js';
        import { RoomEnvironment } from './jsm/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';

        let container    
        let camera, scene, renderer, controls, gui, guiData;
        let model;

        const FemaleModel = 'models/gltf/FemaleModel/';
        

            const Face = {
                'Face 01': 'Female Head 01.glb',
                'Face 02': 'Female Head 02.glb',
                'Face 03': 'Female Head 03.glb',
            };
            const Hair = {
                'Hair 01': 'Female Hair 01.glb',
                'Hair 02': 'Female Hair 02.glb',
                'Hair 03': 'Female Hair 03.glb',
            };

        init();
        
        render();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.set( 150, 200, 250 );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // scene

                const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xdeebed );
                scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene( new RoomEnvironment() ).texture;

                controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

                guiData = {
                    hairFileName: Hair[ 'Face 01' ],
                    faceFileName: Face[ 'Face 01' ],
                    
                };

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

                reloadObject( true );
        }   
            

        function reloadObject( resetCamera ) {

                if ( model ) {

                    scene.remove( model );

                }

                model = null;    

                const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath(FemaleModel)

                loader.load(guiData.faceFileName, function ( ShowFace ) {
                        if ( ShowFace ) {

                            scene.remove( ShowFace );

                        }
                        model = ShowFace.scene;

                        

                        scene.add( model );

                        


                        createGUI();
                        
                        
            }, onError );
            
            

           
        }
        function createGUI() {

                if ( gui ) {

                    gui.destroy();

                }

            gui = new GUI();

            gui.add( guiData, 'faceFileName', Face ).name( 'Face' ).onFinishChange( function () {

                reloadObject( true );

                } );
            gui.add( guiData, 'hairFileName', Hair ).name( 'Hair' ).onFinishChange( function () {

                reloadObject( true );

                } );

            }

           
        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onError() {

        const message = 'Error loading model';
        
        console.log( message );

        }
        

        function render() {

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Keep in mind that [`GLTFLoader.load()` can take up to 4 arguments](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.load). 1st is the URL, 2nd is `onLoad`, 3rd is `onProgress`, and 4th is `onError`. It looks like you're attempting to use the 3rd for error-handling, which would be incorrect.

Comment: No details other than the message that I wrote which is error loading model which doesn't give much info.

Comment: Right. `'Error loading model'` is the error message that you wrote yourself, so it's not gonna give you any more info than that. If there's no red error text, it means it's not really running into an error, because GLTFLoader would automatically tell you what the problem is. Did you fix the arguments in the `.load()` method?

Comment: @Marquizzo I removed "onError", I am not getting any errors but also no model is appearing which is rather strange. I'm not sure how to diagnose the issue.